# Quicktime - Wmode Transparent problem

Tags: html, internet-explorer, quicktime, wmode

Embedding a Quicktime video on a page as a graceful fallback for the IE family of browsers (no flash / html5). I have a div overlaying the video later on, so the Quicktime embed must be wmode=transparent. Below is the embed code:

```
<embed src="test.mp4" width="300" height="400" wmode="transparent" autoplay="true" scale="tofit" />
```

The problem is: the embed area flashes white before loading the quicktime plugin. Embed succesfully completes and video begins playing, the controlbar however is blocked out white.

[image: What quicktime looks like]

Any ideas as how to fix this? (Changing wmode is not an option). This occurs in all IE browsers + FF3.6 (haven't tested higher versions).

Thanks.

Comment: Are you testing this in ieTester / browser labs, or on a standalone version of IE?

Comment: Real version of IE running in a VM. Also occurs on Firefox.

Comment: Can I have a link to an example page (with the test.mp4 that you are using)? And what OS is the VM? Also version of quicktime?

Comment: Are you saying that ie doesn't support Flash, or is this fallback in case it *doesn't* support flash? Graceful degradation means that you *don't* need a working version for users that don't meet the minimum specs, instead, provide a link to the video so they can download or watch it elsewhere.

Comment: @zzzzBov: it is a fallback. Unfortunately we have to meet the client's demands and sending a large part of their demographic to download the video will reduce views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The player hiding the control bar in IE is because of `wmode="transparent"`. Live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3yBR/16/), tested in all versions of IE (6/7/8 and 9) and I saw the same behavior
However setting `wmode="opaque"` shows the control bar. Live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3yBR/10/), tested in all versions of IE (6/7/8 and 9) and saw the same behavior. But the issue with `wmode="opaque"` is we cannot show any overlay (dom element) on top of the player.

FF 3.6 with `wmode="transparent"` do not show anything, I mean the player itself is not visible. Live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3yBR/16/).
But with `wmode="opaque"` everything works fine without any issue, we can have overlay also on top of the player. Live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3yBR/10/)

In Chrome 13 with `wmode="transparent"` everything works fine. Live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3yBR/16/).
But with `wmode="opaque"` the only issue is we cannot show any overlay on top of the player. Live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3yBR/10/)

I think this will give you enough idea about the issues with Quicktime player across most of the modern browsers related to `wmode` and `control bar` problems.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3yBR/16/)**

- This works in all browsers IE (all versions), and Chrome 13. In FF 3.6 works only with `wmode="opaque"` and also supports overlay. So for FF you might want to set `wmode` conditionally.

Working demo with bgiframe for overlay.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3yBR/23/

Comment: Thank you, but I was aware of these findings. My problem is making transparent work in IE since we do need an overlay on top of it. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Dmitri - When we set `wmode="transparent"` the control bar disappers but overlay works and with `wmode="opaque"` the control bar appears but overlay do not work, in this case why dont you use iframe behind the overlay that way control bar will also appear and overlay will also work.

Comment: @Dimitri - Please check my edited answer, have added a working demo which works in all the browsers with control bar and overlay on top of it.

Comment: Thanks Shankar. It still doesn't seem to solve the issue of IE display?

Comment: This works in Firefox + Chrome, however it seems that the initial problem in IE remains. I have tried using bgiframe to automatically add the iframe but unfortunately it did not work in this situation.

Comment: I tried in IE 6/7/8 and it works fine. I am seeing the control bar as well as overlay. If you want I will write a code to show the iframe behind the overlay.

Comment: @Dimitri - Please check my edited answer, I have added bgiframe for Overlay. You can use that code conditionally for IE browser to show the overlay on top of the player, thanks.

Comment: This answer still DOES NOT seem to display the QuickTime controls. (WIN7/CHROME/FF while using wmode=trans)

Answer (score 2):

> The HEIGHT attribute specifies the height of the embedded file in
>   pixels. The HEIGHT attribute is required unless the HIDDEN attribute
>   is specified. The HEIGHT of the movie can be found by choosing 'Get
>   Info...' in the 'Movie' menu within QuickTime Player. If you do not
>   use the SCALE attribute and you supply a height that is smaller than
>   the actual height of the movie (plus 16 if you are showing the
>   controller), the movie will be cropped to fit the height. If you
>   supply a height that is greater than the height of the movie, the
>   movie will be centered inside this height.
>
> Note:Never specify a height of less than 2 as this can cause problems
>   with some browsers.
>
> **> Note 2:The movie controller is 16 pixels high, so add 16 pixels to the
>   height of the movie to make the movie controller visible.**

```
<embed src="test.mp4" width="300" height="416" wmode="transparent" autoplay="true" scale="tofit" />
```

adding 16 to your embed height for controller and/or scale="aspect" will solve your problem according to documents. I don't have lower IE version to test, so, pls let me know.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. Unfortunately as you can see in the screenshot the controlbar is there, but it has an artifact imposed in front of it. I will try out using aspect

Comment: Yep. On top of that using, scale="aspect" keeps the artifact in place, plus adds white sidebars on either side of the video. Thanks!

Comment: could you tell my your QuickTime version?